# A Registration system using HTML and Microsoft Excel/Access

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, ms-access, excel

My friend asked me to make a registration software for his blood donation camp. He told me that he can't host an ASP.NET or PHP page.

Also that since they'll be running the software in many systems, which may not be interconnected, they may not be able to use a Database server.

Is there a way to store/read data from an MS-Excel or MS-Access file instead of any other database?

Also that I wish to make the front end using HTML & JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: Have you looked at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? It's more platform independent than MS Office apps, more has a small footprint, and is "self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional".

Comment: Given that this data is likely to be very confidential you'd have to check with the legal folks to see if storing the data unencrypted inside MS Access database file, or any other solution for that matter, is appropriate.

Comment: Your question is nonsense, because an MS Access file *is* a database.

Comment: Jet/ACE is not a good candidate for use with a web server unless the data is read-only. I would suggest you investigate what options there are on your web server. Most web hosts that I know of provide one or two website-appropriate databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL. With an ASP site, I'd expect them to offer SQL Server as an option.

Comment: @David,
He just asked for the solution as the requirement is from his friends side. They want to run app on multiple machine but not network. So there is no space for the word database server. Look at his statement "Also that since they'll be running the software in many systems, which may not be interconnected, they may not be able to use a Database server." He is asking about feasibility of standalone app using HTML & JavaScript/JQuery and Excel or Access. So the question is no nonsense.

Comment: Jet/ACE is not an appropriate datastore for any browser-based application. Period. End of statement. If you have designed a system around using it that way, then you've made a major error in judgment. My pointing that out is valuable information, even if it's non-negotiable to the original poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you problem is little bit twicky. Since your app will run on various machine so you want to  develop standalone app in Html / Jquery.  Also you cannot use db server bcoz of lack of connectivity. So in such scenario i will suggest you to go for Win Form app with a lightweight db like MS Access and Sqlite. Which ever you prefer. Since you are keeping Network aside so i suggest you to  not use HTML/Jquery to use access or Excel as it looks logical very easy to use interop with excel but implementation is quite messy. In that time you can finalize the winform app with any of the database with lots of ease.